# is it possible to extend keycloak's views like the group creation Page?

Tags: keycloak

I would like to extend the metadata of groups by extending the group creation form with the some extra needed fields. Using attributes is not possible because of the constrained  length of attributes and they may be forgotten during creation. Is there some documentation about it? I would appretiate any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is quit easy. Just customize with an own type (admin, login etc) the corresponding view e.g. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/admin/resources/partials/create-group.html as stated in the keycloak documentation.